# GROUP BY in UPDATE FROM clause

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I really need do something like that:

```
UPDATE table t1 
SET column1=t2.column1 
FROM table t2 
INNER JOIN table t3 
USING (column2) 
GROUP BY t1.column2;
```

But postgres is saying that I have syntax error about GROUP BY clause. What is a different way to do this?

Comment: I think you need to demonstrate more clearly what you want: referring to "t2.column1" when you're grouping by "t1.column2" wouldn't make sense in a plain query, either. You're also not specifying any condition joining t2 and t1, which doesn't really make sense.

Comment: i don't think it can be done with mysql at least

Answer (score 85, accepted):

The UPDATE statement does not support GROUP BY, see [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-update.html). If you're trying to update t1 with the corresponding row from t2, you'd want to use the WHERE clause something like this:

```
UPDATE table t1 SET column1=t2.column1
FROM   table t2
JOIN   table t3 USING (column2)
WHERE  t1.column2=t2.column2;
```

If you need to group the rows from t2/t3 before assigning to t1, you'd need to use a subquery something like this:

```
UPDATE table t1 SET column1=sq.column1
FROM  (
   SELECT t2.column1, column2
   FROM   table t2
   JOIN   table t3 USING (column2)
   GROUP  BY column2
   ) AS sq
WHERE  t1.column2=sq.column2;
```

Although as formulated that won't work because t2.column1 isn't included in the GROUP BY statement (it would have to be an aggregate function rather than a simple column reference).

Otherwise, what exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: I didn't understand what he was trying to do either but this response was still quite helpful for me =)

Answer (score 0):

In MariaDB/ MySQL this SQL work :

```
 UPDATE table t1 left join (
   SELECT t2.column1, column2
   FROM   table t2
   JOIN   table t3 USING (column2)
   GROUP  BY column2
   ) AS sq on t1.column2=sq.column2 
SET column1=sq.column1;
```