# Update a subtable

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a subtable called `result`.

```
SELECT school, grade 
  FROM (SELECT school, grade 
          FROM simulated_records 
         LIMIT 10) as result
```

How would i update the columns of this subtable?  I tried:

```
UPDATE result 
   SET grade = 'A'
```

...but I get an error.

Comment: A named sub-select is not a table. You would update the simulated_records table directly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [updating table rows in postgres using subquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256610/updating-table-rows-in-postgres-using-subquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sub*selects* are temporary, they can't be updated. It sounds like you want a [temporary table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-createtableas.html)

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_grades AS
SELECT school, grade FROM simulated_records;
UPDATE temp_grades SET grade = 'A';
```

EDIT: re your comment:

```
UPDATE simulated_records
FROM (SELECT id FROM simulated_records WHERE school='Yale' LIMIT 10) AS result
SET grade='A'
WHERE id = result.id
RETURNING *;
```

The above uses the UPDATE FROM table operation using a subselect

EDIT 2: for second comment:

Assuming you don't have a typo maybe you have an old version. There's an alternative way to do this with better support:

```
UPDATE simulated_records SET grade = 'A' WHERE id IN
  (SELECT id FROM simulated_records WHERE school = 'Yale' LIMIT 10);
```

Comment: In reality what I want to do is update the first n elements of the original table that meet a certain criteria, say school is 'Yale'. Any idea?

Comment: be clearer, do you want to permanently modify the *original* table or not?

Comment: I get a syntax error                                                                          ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FROM"
LINE 2: FROM (SELECT id FROM simulated_records WHERE school='Yale' L...
        ^

********** Error **********

     ERROR: syntax error at or near "FROM"
     SQL state: 42601
     Character: 26