# PostgreSQL GROUP BY LOWER() not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I am trying to use `GROUP BY` in PostgreSQL 9.4.1 and not having as much success as I hoped.

There are [several folks](http://bytes.com/topic/postgresql/answers/422112-group-case-insensitivity) on [the web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285067/sql-how-to-merge-case-insensitive-duplicates) that claim this should work, but I can't get the same results. All I want is a case-insensitive `GROUP BY` but every time I add `LOWER()` it complains with:

> ERROR: column "people.fn" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be
>   used in an aggregate function

```
CREATE DATABASE TEST;
CREATE TABLE people (id INTEGER, fn TEXT, ln TEXT); /* ID, firstname, lastname */

INSERT INTO people (id, fn, ln) VALUES(1,'Mike','f');
INSERT INTO people (id, fn, ln) VALUES(2,'adam','b');
INSERT INTO people (id, fn, ln) VALUES(3,'bill','b');
INSERT INTO people (id, fn, ln) VALUES(4,'Bill','r');
INSERT INTO people (id, fn, ln) VALUES(5,'mike','d');
INSERT INTO people (id, fn, ln) VALUES(6,'mike','c');
INSERT INTO people (id, fn, ln) VALUES(7,'Mike','T');

SELECT fn FROM people GROUP BY LOWER(fn);  /* will not run */
SELECT fn FROM people GROUP BY fn;  /* runs, but not what I want */
```

Here's what I get:

```
adam
mike
Mike
bill
Bill
```

Here's what I want:

```
Mike
adam
bill
```

Obviously, there's something I'm missing. And no, I can't just sanitize the data as I put it into the database. What should I read to understand this?

Comment: Use LOWER in SELECT as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Generally, if you want to select something in the aggregate query, you have to group by this "something". In your case, you can get results you want by selecting `lower(fn)`:

```
select lower(fn)
from people
group by lower(fn)
```

Luckily, PostgreSQL allows you to group by alias, so you don't have to repeat `lower(fn)` twice:

```
select lower(fn) as lfn
from people
group by lfn
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5a234/4)</kbd>**

As @okaram mentioned in the comments, if you don't need any other aggrgation on the table, you'd better use `distinct`:

```
select distinct lower(fn)
from people
```

Comment: Wonderful. I knew it would be something simple. Thanks Roman.

Comment: This is because there could be several values in the same group, and SQL cannot decide which want you want; Mike mike MIKE would all map to mike, so the same group (mike) would have more than one value, which can't happen

Comment: And you probably want DISTINCT rather than GROUP BY here, as in SELECT DISTINCT LOWER(fn) FROM people