# SELECTing all columns but filter rows by one column

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with the columns `key_id, account_id, title, bpic, description, legal, address`, where the primary key is `key_id`. But I have a problem regarding the `title` of some entries, some titles use capital letters and others don't, which results in getting two identical titles. For example, one row has the title "abcd123" and another "Abcd123". I want to know how I can get all the rows but filter out the duplicates using `group by`, it doesn't matter which one of the two rows is left, I only need to get rid of one of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PostgreSQL GROUP BY LOWER() not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29856589/postgresql-group-by-lower-not-working)

Comment: @NickODell That would be perfect, but I need data from all columns, not just get the titles

Comment: How about `SELECT DISTINCT ON (LOWER(title), * ... ` like in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42556344/aggregate-function-that-returns-any-value-for-a-group

Comment: The best option would be:  1. fix the data by identifying and correcting/deleting duplicates. 2. define new column (example ltitle) as  `ltitle text generated always as (lower (title)) stored` [see demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=cab4d432adff1fb65b8086170d43b589). 3 Put a unique constraint on `ltitle`. 4. Run queries against `ltitle` not `title`