# Efficient way to update multiple fields of Django model object

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to update user in Django database.

Fetched data is as follows :

```
fetched_data = {
     'id': 1,
     'first_name': 'John',
     'last_name': 'Doe',
     'phone': '+32 12',
     'mobile_phone': '+32 13',
     'email': 'myemail@hotmail.com',
     'username': 'myusername'
}
```

I get the user with this **id** as follows :

```
old_user = User.objects.get(pk=fetched_data['id'])
```

If I update the user as follows :

```
old_user.username = fetched_data['username']
old_user.first_name = fetched_data['first_name']
......
old_user.save()
```

it works fine, but I do not want to do it for every record, thus I tried something like :

```
for fetched_data_key in fetched_data:
    old_user.fetched_data_key = fetched_data['fetched_data_key']
    //old_user[fetched_data_key] = fetched_data['fetched_data_key'] --- I tried this way to
    old_user.save()
```

But that doesn't work. Any idea how can I update the user without doing it for every record?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can update a row in the database without fetching and deserializing it; [`update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#update) can do it. E.g.:

```
User.objects.filter(id=data['id']).update(email=data['email'], phone=data['phone'])
```

This will issue one SQL `update` statement, and is much faster than the code in your post. It will never fetch the data or waste time creating a `User` object.

You cannot, though, send a whole bunch of update data to the SQL database and ask it to map it to different rows in one go. If you need a massive update like that done very quickly, your best bet is probably inserting the data into a separate table and then [update it form a `select` on that table](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6258586/223424). Django ORM does not support this, as far as I can tell.

Comment: When creating an object I know you can do something like `e = User(**data)`. Would this work for update?

Comment: @DjangoBlockchain: It may, but it will defeat the purpose of this answer. The idea is to _not_ create an ORM model object for each DB record you want to update. It _really_ kills performance.

Comment: I ended up doing `User.objects.filter(id=data['id']).update(**data)`, so it just updates every field instead of specifying individual fields. Sorry if my question was confusing.

Answer (score 34):

Even simpler if you use [`.update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#update) method of [`QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/) object as:

```
my_id = fetched_data.pop('id')  # remove 'id' from `fetch_data`
                                # as it is not supposed to be updated

User.objects.filter(pk=my_id).update(**fetched_data)
#          unpack the content of `dict` ^
```

It will unpack the content of `fetched_data` dict and will update the records in `User` object whose columns are present as *key* to the `fetched_data` dict. Since you are calling filter on `pk`, it will always return single record.

Comment: what if I need to update only one object from the queryset?

Comment: "pk" is the unique key in your Django model. On filtering based on it will return you  a QuerySet containing only one object.

Comment: the problem is I am not using 'pk'

Comment: @brainLoop : By default "pk" references the primary key column of your Django model.

Comment: @Anonymous I did exactly the same as you explained. The record is updated but my updated_at (auto_now) field is not getting updated. Maybe because we are not doing `Obj.save()`.

Comment: this answer is a lifesaver!!! This approach works on any NoSQL based database

Answer (score 17):

If you use `.update` then there is an issue, since it won't raise **post_save** or **pre_save** signal, so if you want to use any signal on any change of data then  `User.objects.filter(pk=fetched_data['id']).update(**kwargs)` won't work.

So you can use `setattr()` to update the fields and then `.save` would save the row which would update the row also raise an signal.

```
old_user = User.objects.get(pk=fetched_data['id'])
for key, value in fetched_data.iteritems():
    setattr(old_user, key, value)
old_user.save()
```

Comment: This is by far the best way to go. Signals are all over the place in all medium and large Django projects; you wouldn't want to tinker with them

Answer (score 6):

```
setattr(old_user, fetched_data_key, fetched_data['fetched_data_key'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
User.objects.filter(pk=fetched_data['id']).update(**kwargs)
```

this will update multiple fields. But it won't call signals, So if there is any signal written for this model then it will not run.

So better to use `setattr()` method to set new data into the fields, then call `.save()` method and it will run the signal also.

```
user = User.objects.get(pk=fetched_data['id'])
for key, value in fetched_data.items():
    setattr(user, key, value)
user.save()
```

Answer (score -1):

> Blackquotes

def update_block(request, id):

```
a = RentedNumberBlock.objects.get(id=id)
b = RentedNumber.objects.filter(user=request.user)
c = a.rented_number.values_list('id', flat=True)
if request.POST:
    update = RentedNumberBlock.objects.get(id=id)
    update.name = request.POST['name']
    z = dict(request.POST)['rented_number']
    y = RentedNumber.objects.filter(id__in=z)
    update.rented_number.set(z)
    update.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/block/')
return render(request, "block/update.html", {"a": a , "b": b, "c": c})
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Thanks for contributing an answer but can you also add an explanation on how your code solves the problem? If you need help with formatting, see the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).