# Set value on table if related table value in array (postgresql)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-update

I have 2 tables, `users` and `profiles`. And I'd like to set `profiles.verified` to `true` if `users.emails` is in a list `('email1','email2',...)`.

Inspired by other SO threads like [updating table rows in postgres using subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256610/updating-table-rows-in-postgres-using-subquery), I've been trying to do something like,

```
UPDATE 
  profiles p1  
SET 
  verified = true
FROM 
  profiles p2
  INNER JOIN users u1 on u1.id = p2.user_id
WHERE 
  u1.email in ('email1','email2',...)
```

But it just updates `profiles.verified` to `true` for all records in `profiles`.

How can I only update `profile` records if they are related to a `users` record with an email in a specified list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Postgres, you don't mention the table being updated twice:

```
UPDATE profiles p1  
    SET verified = true
FROM users u1 
WHERE u1.id = p1.user_id AND
      u1.email in ('email1', 'email2', ...)
```