# Problem in PostgreSQL (ERROR: relation "a" does not exist)

Tags: sql, postgresql

SQL query (PostgreSQL) looks like that:

```
UPDATE a
SET "PropertyAddress" = COALESCE(a."PropertyAddress", b."PropertyAddress")
FROM "NashvilleHousingData" a
INNER JOIN "NashvilleHousingData" b
    ON a."ParcelID" = b."ParcelID"
    AND a."UniqueID" <> b."UniqueID"
WHERE a."PropertyAddress" IS NULL;
```

And the error is `relation "a" does not exist`

I tried other advices about the notion in the code public or scheme, but it still doesn't work. Please, help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [updating table rows in postgres using subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256610/updating-table-rows-in-postgres-using-subquery)

Answer (score 2):

This is not how Postgres handles updates with more than one table.  You don't repeat the table in the `from` clause:

```
UPDATE "NashvilleHousingData" nhd
    SET "PropertyAddress" = COALESCE(nhd."PropertyAddress", nhd2."PropertyAddress")
FROM "NashvilleHousingData" nhd2
WHERE nhd2."ParcelID" = nhd."ParcelID" AND
      nhd2."UniqueID" <> nhd."UniqueID"
WHERE nhd."PropertyAddress" IS NULL;
```

Also, the `COALESCE()` is superfluous because the value is known to be `NULL`:

```
    SET "PropertyAddress" = nhd2."PropertyAddress"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I need to use JOIN in order to unite information from different columns in one column. Like before this query I did 
`SELECT a."ParcelID", a."PropertyAddress", b."ParcelID", b."PropertyAddress",
       COALESCE(b."PropertyAddress", a."PropertyAddress")
FROM "NashvilleHousingData" a
INNER JOIN "NashvilleHousingData" b
    ON a."ParcelID" = b."ParcelID"
    AND a."UniqueID" <> b."UniqueID"
WHERE a."PropertyAddress" IS NULL;` and this work, but the next query gives me error

Comment: @eliz . . . You do not need an explicit `JOIN`.  This does what you are trying to do.  The `JOIN` is happening, but using the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: I think you want `AND` instead of two `WHERE`.
WHERE nhd2."ParcelID" = nhd."ParcelID" AND
      nhd2."UniqueID" <> nhd."UniqueID"
WHERE nhd."PropertyAddress" IS NULL;