# MySQL - Update X where Y is lowest

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have following table:

```
       TableA
  x               y
----------------------
 3                1
 2                5
 5                2
```

Now i want to update the value in column x, where the value in column y is lowest, something like that:

```
UPDATE TableA SET x = 1 WHERE y = min(y);
```

Then the first row should be x = 1 and y = 1.

But i get following error code:

```
Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function
```

How can i fix that?

Comment: You are getting that error because `min` is an aggregate function and you need a `group by` clause to use aggregate functions.

Comment: Here is an answer that may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/5272523

Comment: @Jeff Burgin Yes, but update doesn't support group by  edit: ok i'll check out the link

Comment: Right, I just was explaining the error you were getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `y` is unique, then you can use `order by` and `limit`:

```
UPDATE TableA
    SET x = 1 
    ORDER BY Y ASC
    LIMIT 1;
```

If you have multiple rows with the minimum value, you can use `join`:

```
UPDATE TableA a JOIN
       (SELECT MIN(Y) as miny FROM TableA) m
       ON a.y = m.miny
    SET x = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write your query as follow:

```
UPDATE TableA SET x = 1 WHERE y IN (select min(y) from TableA T2);
```

Comment: In MySQL you can't reference the table being updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TableA
    JOIN (SELECT min(y) as min_y, FROM TableA GROUP BY y) 
      as temp ON temp.min_y = TableA.y
   SET x = 1;
```