# Why do I get this 'GROUP BY' error when using 'UPDATE' (SQL)?

Tags: sql, group-by, having

I'm trying to increase the employee salaries by 50% for all employees except those currently earning the highest salary:

```
UPDATE employees
SET emp_salary= emp_salary + (emp_salary * 50)/100
GROUP BY emp_salary
HAVING emp_salary < (select max(emp_salary) from employees);
```

But I get this error:
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "GROUP"
LINE 3:     GROUP BY emp_salary

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need group by / having you need `where`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot use `update` with `group by`. Instead, you can do your grouping in a subquery:

```
UPDATE E1
SET 
    emp_salary= emp_salary + (emp_salary * 50)/100
FROM
    employees E1
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        -- Not really grouping anything here - so just a pointless example!
        SELECT emp_id
        FROM employees
        GROUP BY emp_salary
        HAVING emp_salary < (select max(emp_salary) from employees)
    ) E2
    ON E1.emp_id = E2.emp_id;
```

As accurately noted by Stu you are not really doing something here that requires grouping, so more simply and effectively in this case just:

```
UPDATE employees
SET 
    emp_salary= emp_salary + (emp_salary * 50)/100
WHERE
    emp_salary < (select max(emp_salary) from employees);
```

Comment: Thank you! In my mind 'WHERE' couldn't be used with aggregate functions but I didn't think about a sub query.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [GROUP BY in UPDATE FROM clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272412/group-by-in-update-from-clause)

And in this case seems, we don't need GROUP BY, you can use only WHERE clause to check the highest salary.

```
UPDATE
  employees
SET
  emp_salary = emp_salary + (emp_salary * 50) / 100
WHERE
  emp_salary < (
    select
      max(emp_salary)
    from
      employees
  );
```